# How to increase performance of ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to know how to increase performance of ViewPager. I have ViewPager which has around  25 swipes with large images. I have done [memory optimization](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) to avoid OutOfMemoryError. Its working fine.But still there is a lag while swiping. I have set offscreen page limit to 2. If I increase offscreen page limit. It will load more pages in Memory and again I will end up with OOM. So any suggestion how to avoid lag while swiping?

Comment: what do you use to get your image? bitmap? drawable?

Comment: have you checked if the swiped views including bitmaps (should be recycled) are properly destroyed in destroyItem method of adapter?

Comment: @NAYOSO i am using setImageBitmap();

Comment: @user936414 yah i am destroying fragment in FragmentStatePagerAdapter's destroyItem() using fragment Transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ViewPager` cannot cache more than 2 pages? It sounds like you need to tweak your fragments a bit more. For example, make sure you [don't stretch the background image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026317/832776), and make sure that your layouts are as simple as possible (i.e. don't use unneeded layouts). If you can see how much memory your app is using for these two pages.

Once you verify that see if you can increase the offscreen page limit. Then check that you [are properly destroying the fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9512630/832776).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) istead using [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html).

More detailed explanation given [here](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/7961-android-adventures-viewpager.html?start=1).

Answer (score 0):

Another Possible solution in case of images is that you can try putting them in drawable-hdpi folder, they will load faster. You can look at an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763407/android-viewpager-lag/18808645#18808645).