# .2 second delay clicking Button on physical device but not emulator

Tags: android

EDIT 2: This happens on my physical Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge running API 23 and not my emulator, Nexus 5X running API 23. I have another physical device which runs Android 5 which animates but not very smoothly. The Nexus 5X API 22 has the same problem as my physical device running API 23. Any ideas why?

Not entirely sure what's going on but when I tap on my `Button`, I get a .2 second delay before I see the logging for it or the animation begins. If I hold click, I visually see the delay as the button background lags and animates.

I get no problem when I don't set the style to Borderless or if I don't have the backgrounds set to `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`. Any idea what's causing this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYes"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAreYouAStudent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNo"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5026042"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="193dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Fragment**:

```
public class StudentFragment extends Fragment
{
    public final String TAG = "StudentFragment";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        Application.component().inject(this);

        return rootView;
    }

@OnClick(R.id.tvYes)
public void yesTapped()
{
    tvYes.animate().scaleX(.85f).scaleY(.85f).setDuration(175);
    tvNo.setScaleX(1);
    tvNo.setScaleY(1);
    Log.e(TAG, "Yes tapped");
}

@OnClick(R.id.tvNo)
public void noTapped()
{
    tvNo.animate().scaleX(.85f).scaleY(.85f).setDuration(175);
    tvYes.setScaleX(1);
    tvYes.setScaleY(1);
    Log.e(TAG, "No tapped");
}
}
```

**Logs:**

As you can see, sometimes there is a 200ms delay particularly in the final 2 taps, sometimes there isn't.

```
12-20 22:57:52.266 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:57:52.366 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:57:52.576 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
12-20 22:57:53.296 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:57:53.446 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:57:53.606 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
12-20 22:57:54.656 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:57:54.716 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:57:54.856 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
12-20 22:57:55.706 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:57:55.766 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:57:55.796 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
12-20 22:57:57.116 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:57:57.166 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:58:00.496 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:58:00.616 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:58:00.826 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:58:00.826 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:58:00.826 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
12-20 22:58:01.656 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:58:01.746 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:58:01.766 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
12-20 22:58:02.756 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:58:02.836 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:58:03.166 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
12-20 22:58:04.296 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-20 22:58:04.396 20549-20549/com D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
12-20 22:58:04.606 20549-20549/com E/StudentFragment: Yes tapped
```

If I am unable to set these, what alternative can I use to emulate a button click? A ripple is ideal as it's Android default.

EDIT: I have tried to set an animation on the buttons by using:  `btnYes.animate().scaleX(.85f).scaleY(.85f).setDuration(175);` and I don't see the animation. I see a delay and then it changes.

I have also tried changing the buttons to `TextView`s with the above change and I still see no animation, just lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background that I was using was placed in `res/drawable`. As soon as I separated it out into the respective drawable folders, all of the lag stopped.

I added a ViewPager to see if that would lag on animation and it did, which then pointed me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808645/4624156).